# Is my proof of the claim in example 5.1.7 in Notes on Elementary Linear Analysis (Bedos) correct?

Tags: functional-analysis, solution-verification, normed-spaces

I am trying to verify a claim in the example below, taken from these notes: [https://www.uio.no/studier/emner/matnat/math/MAT4400/v19/pensumliste/ela-190523.pdf](https://www.uio.no/studier/emner/matnat/math/MAT4400/v18/notes/elav1.0.pdf).

[image]

Notation:

$\ell^p(\mathbb{N}) = \{ (x(n))_n \subset \mathbb{N} : \|(x(n))_n\|_p < \infty \}$.

$\ell^\infty(\mathbb{N}) = \{ (x(n))_n \subset \mathbb{N} : \|(x(n))_n\|_\infty < \infty \}$.

$\|(x(n))_n\|_p = \left( \sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \lvert x(n) \rvert^p \right)^{1/p}$.

$\|(x(n))_n\|_\infty = \sup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \lvert x(n) \rvert$.

$\mathcal{B}(X) =$ the set of bounded linear operators from $X$ into $X$

$\overline{\mathcal{F}(X,X)} =$ the closure of the set of bounded finite rank operators from $X$ to $X$.

$\mathcal{K}(X,X) =$ the set of compact operators from $X$ to $X$.

$\|\cdot\|$ denotes the operator norm.

**I am trying to show the first claim, i.e.**

> $$\|M_\lambda \| = \| \lambda \|_\infty.$$

**Attempt:**

$\|M_\lambda \| \leq \| \lambda \|_\infty$:

\begin{align*} 
\|M_\lambda(x) \|_p &= \|(\lambda(n) x(n))_n \|_p \\
&\leq \sup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \lvert \lambda(n) \rvert \|(x(n))_n\|_p \\
&= \|\lambda\|_\infty \|(x(n))_n\|_p
\end{align*}

Hence $\|M_\lambda\| \leq \|\lambda\|_\infty$.

Now to show equality:

Fix a $\lambda \in \ell^\infty(\mathbb{N})$.

Let $N$ denote the first index $n$ for which $\lvert \lambda(n) \rvert = \sup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \lvert \lambda(n) \rvert$

Let $(x(n))_n \in \ell^p$ be defined by $x(n) = \begin{cases} 1 \ \text{if} \ n = N, \\ 0 \ \text{otherwise}. \end{cases}$

Then

\begin{align*}
\|M_\lambda(x)\|_p &= \left( \sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \lvert \lambda(n)x(n) \rvert^p \right)^{1/p} \\
&= \left( \lvert \lambda(N) \cdot 1 \rvert^p\right)^{1/p} \\ &= \lvert \lambda(N) \rvert \\
&= \|\lambda\|_\infty.
\end{align*}

Hence $\|M_\lambda\| = \|\lambda\|_\infty$.

Correct? My feeling is that $N$ being the first index for which something is equal to its supremum sounds kind of iffy...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mistake is assuming there exists $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $|\lambda(n)|=\|\lambda\|_{\infty}.$ For example, let $\lambda(n)=1-\dfrac1n.$ Then $\lambda \in l^{\infty}(\mathbb{N})$ and $\|\lambda\|_{\infty}=1$ but $\not\exists\ n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\lambda(n)=1.$

**Correct argument:** Fix $\epsilon >0$ and $M=\|\lambda\|_{\infty}.$ Then there exists $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $|\lambda(N)|\geq M-\epsilon.$ Let $(x(n))_n \in \ell^p$ be defined by $$x(n) = \begin{cases} 1 \ \text{if} \ n = N, \\ 0 \ \text{otherwise}. \end{cases}$$

Then \begin{align*}
\|M_\lambda(x)\|_p &= \left( \sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \lvert \lambda(n)x(n) \rvert^p \right)^{1/p} \\
&= \left( \lvert \lambda(N) \cdot 1 \rvert^p\right)^{1/p} \\ &= \lvert \lambda(N) \rvert \\
&\geq M-\epsilon.
\end{align*}

Thus $\|M_{\lambda}\|\geq M-\epsilon$ for every $\epsilon >0.$ Hence $\|M_{\lambda}\|\geq M.$